# How to show that the limit of this sequence is $L=4$ (ex.8.11 Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed.- Apostol)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that the sequence given by $$\begin{aligned}a_1&=2\\a_2&=8\\a_{2n+1}&=\frac{a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}}2\\a_{2n+2}&=\frac{a_{2n}a_{2n-1}}{a_{2n+1}}\end{aligned}$$ has limit $L=4$.

I know the principle of mathematical induction could be useful, but I can't understand the way I should use this principle to prove the limit is $L=4.$

I am interested in understanding how I should think when I face this kind of problems.
Could you help me,  please? Any hint or help will be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $a_{2n}a_{2n-1}=a_2a_1=16$ for every $n$, the sequence $b_n=a_{2n-1}$ solves $b_1=a_1=2$ and $b_{n+1}=\frac12\left(b_{n}+\frac{a_1a_2}{b_n}\right)=\frac12\left(b_n+\frac{16}{b_{n}}\right)$ for every $n\geqslant 1$.

Let $u:x\mapsto\frac12\left(x+\frac{16}{x}\right)$, then $u(x)\geqslant4$ for every $x\gt0$, $u(4)=4$ and $4\leqslant u(x)\leqslant x$ on $x\geqslant4$, thus $b_n\geqslant4$ for every $n\geqslant2$ and $(b_n)_{n\geqslant2}$ is lower bounded by $4$ and nonincreasing.

In particular, $b_n\to\ell$ when $n\to\infty$, where $\ell\geqslant4$ solves $u(\ell)=\ell$, that is, $\ell=4$. Finally, $a_{2n}=2b_{n+1}-b_n$ hence $a_{2n}\to2\ell-\ell=\ell$ as well. QED.

For other positive values of $(a_1,a_2)$, replace $16$ by $a_1a_2$ and $\ell=4$ by $\ell=\sqrt{a_1a_2}$, then the result still holds.

Comment: @PedroMilet Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @PedroMilet Thank you. I'm slowly digesting your answer. There are a couple of things I can't get.  **1.** How can we say that $b_{n+1}=\frac12\left(b_{n}+\frac{a_1a_2}{b_n}\right)$  **2.** Does $b_n \to \ell$ as $n \to \infty$ because it is lower bounded and nonincreasing?  **3.** Why does $\ell$ solve $u(\ell)=\ell$?

Comment: 0. I am not @PedroMilet. 1. Direct consequence of the definition of $a_{2n+1}$ in terms of $a_{2n-1}$ and $a_{2n}=a_1a_2/a_{2n-1}$. 2. Yes. 3. Because $u$ is continuous.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that $2\leq a_{2n+2}\leq a_{2n+1} \leq8$,  in order to complete a proof that I am trying to do (using your help). I would use the principle of Mathematical Induction. So the statement with n=1 is true because we have $a_4=3,2\leq a_3=5$. Now I need to prove that $2\leq a_{2n+2}\leq a_{2n+1} \leq8 \implies 2\leq a_{2(n+1)+2}\leq a_{2(n+1)+1} \leq8$. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: One already knows that $4\lt a_{2n+1}\leqslant a_3$ for every $n\geqslant1$. And $a_{2n}=16/a_{2n-1}$ shows that $16/a_3\leqslant a_{2n}\lt4$ for every $n\geqslant2$. Hence $16/5\leqslant a_{2n+2}\lt4\lt a_{2n+1}\leqslant5$ for every  $n\geqslant1$--a stronger statement than what you are interested in.

Comment: **1.** $4<a_{2n+1}\leq a_3$ because $4\leq u\colon x \mapsto \frac x2 + \frac8x\leq 5$ for $n\ge1$ **2.** $a_{2n}=\frac{16}{a_{2n-1}}$ shows that $\frac{16}{a_3}\leq a_{2n}$ because the odd subsequence is lower or equal than $a_3$ for $n\ge 1$ and finally **3.** $a_{2n}\leq 4$ because $$a_{2n+2}=\frac{16}{4\leq a_{2n+1}\leq 5}.$$ Ok? God Bless you Did.

Answer (score 3):

The starting numbers are a and b.

$$c:=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

$$d:=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$$

are the next two numbers.

So, the product of the two numbers is

cd = ab , so the product does not change in the process.

If L is the limit, we have $L^2 = ab = 16$ , so L = 4.

Comment: The answer is useful, but since I'm a beginner, do you mind if I ask you to be more explicit? Instead of concentrating on the answer, I would like to understand what's the logic you used...

Comment: The key is that the pair ($a_{2n-1},a_{2n}$) maps to the pair ($a_{2n+1},a_{2n+2}$), such that the product of the numbers within a pair remains constant.

Comment: Clearly, c is smaller than a, if a is the larger member. So, b is smaller than d because of the equation d=$\frac{ab}{c}$. Since the arithmetic mean is larger than the harmonic mean, the number c is the new larger member. Since it is smaller than a, the larger member decrease, so the smaller members must increase because the product is constant. So the sequence of pairs converges to (4,4).